# How to remove or delete a service using 'service resource' within Chef?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am using the `service resource` as below:

```
service "chef-client" do
  service_name "chef-client"
  action [ :stop, :disable ]
end
```

However, instead of disabling the service `I want to remove or delete the service.`

Answer (score 0):

This is not something Chef has an abstraction for. Service frameworks are very widely varying in how a "remove" action would work so coming up with a "smallest common API" would be tricky. My `poise_service` resource does manage the underlying files but it can only remove a service it created generally speaking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best you would be able to do is stop/disable the service and then use a package declaration to remove it.

https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html

probably :remove or :purge depending on if you want to kill config files also.

Comment: you should try always to avoid using links for answering the questions, since links break on time. You should try to quote the most relevant part of the content shown on the link you mentioned.